# Line animation in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-animation

I am trying to do animating line drawing in xcode. I am developing for iPhone. I found some tutorials which use CABasicAnimation. But, when I try to create an CABasicAnimation object like this

```
CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
```

I get an error: use of undeclared identifier CABasicAnimation.

Do I need some library for using CABasicAnimation object? I am not sure how is this working. Is there any tutorial that explain complete process of animation in Xcode, because all I found is starting with defining CABasicAnimation object, without any explanation what should I configure or import before.

I am using XCode 4.4.1 and a Mountain Lion. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include QuartzCore.framework into your project and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your code

[image]